# Java Instant's bug? `DateTimeException: Invalid value for Year`

Tags: java, java-time

According to the [documentation for Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html), the minimum Instant is `-1000000000-01-01T00:00Z`, so the year is `-1000000000` and the timezone is `UTC`. so I expected this program to work, and the `atOffset` to be a noop:

```java
import java.time.*;

public class A {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Instant i = Instant.MIN;
      System.out.println(i);
      System.out.println(i.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC));
   }
}
```

But instead it throws this exception on the `atOffset`:

```
-1000000000-01-01T00:00:00Z
Exception in thread "main" java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for Year (valid values -999999999 - 999999999): -1000000000
        at java.time.temporal.ValueRange.checkValidIntValue(ValueRange.java:330)
        at java.time.temporal.ChronoField.checkValidIntValue(ChronoField.java:722)
        at java.time.LocalDate.ofEpochDay(LocalDate.java:341)
        at java.time.LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(LocalDateTime.java:422)
        at java.time.OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(OffsetDateTime.java:328)
        at java.time.Instant.atOffset(Instant.java:1195)
        at A.main(A.java:7)
```

Is that a bug? According to that validation's message the minimum year is `-999999999` but the documentation says it is `-1000000000`.

Comment: No, it is not a bug. You're converting to OffsetDateTime and it has different MIN and MAX values. Read the [**documentation of OffsetDateTime**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) to see for yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`atOffset` returns an [OffsetDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) which has a different Min/Max.

> The minimum supported OffsetDateTime, '-999999999-01-01T00:00:00+18:00'.
>
> The maximum supported OffsetDateTime, '+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999-18:00'.

The javadoc mentions that these min/max values are derived from [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#MIN) along with the max zone offsets, which appears to be why they don't match up to Instant.

The reason Instant has an extra year both ways, per documentation of [Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html).

> This is one year earlier than the minimum LocalDateTime. This provides sufficient values to handle the range of ZoneOffset which affect the instant in addition to the local date-time. The value is also chosen such that the value of the year fits in an int.

Covers the edge case where a LocalDateTime + Offset results in a time from the previous year.

The max practical value would be the minimum OffsetDateTime converted to an Instant, as everything prior to that date is a buffer for which there is no equivalent OffsetDateTime.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug, actually the action of invoking

```
i.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

triggers the creation of a `OffsetDateTime` object which the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#MIN) clearly states the following

> The minimum supported OffsetDateTime, '-999999999-01-01T00:00:00+18:00'.

So basically if you keep it an `Instant` it's ok, but trying to change it may cause a problem